# Which of the "design" tags should be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

- [design](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) × 55 - a broad term for something that has been created from a plan, there are thousands of types of design types (Web Design, Graphic Design, 3D Design, Etc.)
- [website-design](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design) × 275 - the process of planning and creating websites that can be read/viewed by web browsers
- [web-design](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-design) × 55 - a broad term used to encompass the way that content is delivered to an end-user through the World Wide Web, using a web browser or other web-enabled software to display the content.
- [responsive-webdesign](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/responsive-webdesign) × 26

Comment: I just created the wiki for the `responsive-webdesign` tag

Comment: I've just merged "web-design" into [Tag:website-design].   Because website-design is used more than 1.5x as often, the tool wouldn't let me do the synonym the other way around.

Answer (score 5):

My two-cents would be to combine `website-design` and `web-design`, but leave the others separate.

Comment: +1: I support this proposal.

Comment: I also agree with this proposal

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would favor just `responsive` over `responsive-webdesign` since this isn't a broad term and most people associate the word responsive with website design in any case and it would be more favorable in my honest opinion to have people tagging both website-design and responsive at the same time rather than one or the other since both are related and would enhance the browsing through tags.

Comment: You wouldn't be worried about "responsive" getting confused with performance issues around how responsive their server is to requests?

Answer (score 0):

[responsive-webdesign](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/responsive-webdesign) is a different concept than the rest.  It should be left separate.  We should write a tag wiki for it.  It should be renamed to be consistent with the main tag for design.

---

The other three are very similar. [web-design](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-design) and  [website-design](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design) mean exactly the same thing to me.

I could see the case for [design](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) being separate as it could have different meanings.  However in the context of this site, which is all about websites, it seems to refer to "web design" in all the tagged questions.  The only exception that I notice is the question [What is good URI design?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2105/what-is-good-uri-design) which is talking about how URLs should look.  When merging the tags, I would un-tag "design" from this question.

I would pick "web-design" as the canonical name for these three tags.

Comment: re. `responsive-webdesign` - the `web` seems redundant since this is a site for webmasters.

Comment: Think that on this site, `web` or `website` prefixes are needless warts